# Bot Framework - Prevent GatewayTimeout for Long Operation

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've built a bot using `botframework` V4 for .Net that replies to user for both **email** and **directline** channels.

However, some of the request takes more than 15 seconds to complete, therefore I'd receive a `GatewayTimeout` error:
[image: Channel Error Log]

These requests are heavy (fetch some data from the database, fetch other data from another server via API calls, process the data, generate HTML and send them back to the user...) therefore nothing can be done to shorten the process.

I am aware that the gateway timeout delay [is by design](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2161#issuecomment-395203623) (the 15 seconds), but the problem is that the channel automatically retries the request after a small period of time and I end up receiving multiple emails for the same query (approx. 1 minute apart each).

I noticed as well that the directline replies are much faster than email ones (websocket vs SMTP), therefore this is mainly occurring with the **email** channel only. Noting that the emails are kept under 300KB as per [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5302#issuecomment-465272396) but can easily have a size close to this limit.

Therefore, is there a way to:

- Increase the timeout delay?
- Disable the automatic retries?
- Or perhaps a certain workaround to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that [your bot is a web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-introduction) that exposes an HTTP endpoint, and every activity sent to your bot is an API call. Long-running API calls should be designed to return a response immediately and do their processing asynchronously. For example, consider the [Recognize Text Computer Vision API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5cd27ec07268f6c679a3e641/operations/587f2c6a1540550560080311). It just returns an [Operation-Location](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5cd27ec07268f6c679a3e641/operations/587f2cf11540550560080312) where the actual result will become available later.

For bot Framework bots, all you have to do to send a message to the channel after the turn already ended is to send a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message). It's often also a good idea to design your bot to give the user an indication that the result is coming, such as by sending a preliminary "processing" message or a typing indicator, but that's probably unwanted in the case of the email channel. Eric Dahlvang explained this in the issue you linked to:

> If the developer knows the response will take longer than 15 seconds, it is possible, depending on the channel, to start a separate thread to handle the long running process, return a valid status code on the receiving thread, and when the process finishes, send a proactive message from the background thread.

Comment: So In other words the bot should return an HTTP 200 response and offload the data fetching/email sending to a background process for example?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki - Yes, exactly. Is this answer acceptable?