# While looping in the loop after few seconds same waterfall step is getting called twice in ms bot framework in MS Teams but not on( Bot Emulator)

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, .net-core-3.1

I have a bot framework application like chatbot in .net core 3.1 which is deployed on Azure. To access this application we are using MS Teams as the channel. In this, we are using waterfallDialog and adaptivecards. we have a scenario in which we are calling a web API to save some data in DB(SQL Server) and just after saving we are looping in a loop for a few second(60 seconds) for some background activity, once this background activity is done then we come out from the loop and go-ahead for the further process and our application is working as expected in bot emulator but not in MS Teams. Here problem is that due to long running process it recalls the same function and hence again it does all the activities again thus the double DB entries. we not able to find out the root cause why this issue is coming in the picture, initially it happened on a button click and now it is happening anywhere in application wherever long running process is going on. As per our finding, waterfall step is calling itself again when inside method took more than 15 seconds and it is being called twice only not thrice. Apart from it, we don't see any error so unable to share anything.

find the below code:

Thanks.

```cs
//below is my waterfall step:

public async Task<DialogTurnResult> PrinterActionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    { 
        BWPrinter bWPrinter = stepContext.Options as BWPrinter;               
       
        //if user confirms the request details and 
        if (((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value == strConfirm)
        {                   
            TaskRequestParams objtaskRequest = new TaskRequestParams();
                            
            objtaskRequest.EmpID = bWPrinter.ObjuserDetails.EmployeeID;
            objtaskRequest.MachineIP = bWPrinter.ObjuserDetails.MachineIP;

            //Call WebAPI to Create Request in DB 
            ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
            paramList.Add(objtaskRequest);
            paramList.Add(bWPrinter.mainMenuItem);
          
            // db hit through web api call to insert record in db.
            var result = await CommonUtility.RestfullWebAPIRequest(configuration.GetValue(typeof(string), BotConstants.ServiceAddress).ToString(), BotConstants.HTTPResponseBotServiceAddress, RequestType.Post.ToString(), paramList);
            var resultSplit = result.Split(",");
            
            if (resultSplit.Length > 1)
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                // max wait time for 60 sec to perform background process.
                double watchTimer = Convert.ToDouble("60"); // duration in second                  
                while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(watchTimer))
                {
                    // db hit through web api call to check request status in db
                    var result = await CommonUtility.RestfullWebAPIRequest(configuration.GetValue(typeof(string), BotConstants.ServiceAddress).ToString(), string.Format(BotConstants.HTTPResponseBotTaskRequestStatus + "/?requestId={0}", requestid), RequestType.Get.ToString(), requestid);
                    resultSplit = result.Split(",");
                    if (resultSplit.Length > 0)
                    {
                        requeststatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(resultSplit[0]);
                        if (requeststatus != RequestStatus.Pending.ToString())
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return await EndDialogCatch(null, stepContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex, BotConstants.CallerFunction + BotUtility.GetCallerFunctionName() + System.Environment.NewLine + BotConstants.ErrorDescription + ex.Message);

        return await EndDialogCatch(ex, stepContext, cancellationToken);
    }
    // When no choice is matching but this function is called - very unlikely
    return await EndDialogCatch(null, stepContext, cancellationToken, ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please share what error you are facing in the console? Also could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/81.skills-skilldialog/DialogRootBot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs)?

Comment: @user3282946 - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Hey @Kyle Delaney thanks for your response, To be more specific I feel the waterfall step calls itself recursively whenever engaged in a long-running process. Initially, we were stuck in a particular scenario but after testing, we could reproduce the same issue in other modules of our project, actually it is calling the same waterfall step again whenever engaged in a long-running process(maybe it takes 20 seconds or 30 seconds to complete) but the bot doesn't wait and calls same waterfall step (mostly in 16 seconds).
 
To add further it happens only in MS Teams but not in Bot Emulator.

Comment: Sorry @Kyle Delaney for late response actually we had few more issues to be fixed so couldn't check this ticket. yes mistake is ours. Request to take a look on this as I have modified the question again.

Comment: @user3282946 - There is an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance) that explains how to handle long-running operations, as well as some Stack Overflow answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105588/2122672), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493632/2122672)

Comment: Hello @Kyle Delaney, Thanks for your positive response.

Comment: Are you willing to accept an answer now?

Answer (score 0):

For better experience coyping comments to answer :

You can send the message to user using waterfall dailog.  Please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/81.skills-skilldialog/DialogRootBot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs)?